# How to update a foreign key without using the controller? - yii, php

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've recently created a database that has a table of a user, mobile_accounts, and paylists. Both the paylists and the mobile_accounts link back to the user and both have the foreign id "user_id". When I am letting users create their own paylists or mobile_accounts, I am using a function that I created in the user model called "addUserId". I call that function in each specific controller (i.e. paylists or in mobile_accounts) passing in both the current model and the user_id. This is working for me fine, but it seems like a bit of a work-around system. 
Am I missing something very simple in terms of how to update my database with a foreign key? Or will I just have to keep on creating functions like this in the future?

Here is the code in the Paylist controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Paylist;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Paylist']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Paylist'];
        if($model->save())
            // adds the current UserId to the table
            User::model()->addUserId($model);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

And here is the code in the User model

```
// adds the user id to your data table, takes in the user id and adds it to specified model 
public function addUserId($model)
{  
    $accountid = $model->id;
    $current_email = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    // gets the current id of the user 
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$current_email));
    // extracts out the id of the current user 
    $user_id = $user->id; 
    $model->updateByPk($accountid,array('user_id'=>$user_id)); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CActiveRecord::beforeSave()` method in your models:

```
public function beforeSave(){
   if($this->isNewRecord){
       User::model()->addUserId($this);
   }
   return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

And change `addUserId` method:

```
public function addUserId($model)
{  
    $accountid = $model->id;
    $current_email = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$current_email));
    $model->user_id = $user->id; ; // just set user_id attribute
}
```

Also you can implement method `getCurrentUserId` in `User` model which returns current user id and invoke this method in `beforeSave`:

```
public function beforeSave(){
   if($this->isNewRecord){
       $this->user_id = User::getCurrentUserId();
   }
   return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: Incredible Answer - thank you so much @Oledje . 
So, to clarify, when I am updating a model -  I do not need to use UpdatebyPK? I can simply go into the model and update it directly with another variable?

Comment: @Stephen as I understand in your `Paylist` `user_id` attribute never changes. If so, then you should set this attribute value only when you create new model (there are `$this->isNewRecord` condition). And when you update existing Paylist model you dont have to update this attribute.

Comment: Also, when I use your new iteration of addUserId   (Where instead of using UpdatebyPK) and I try to call it from the controller in the previous position I had (right inside the if(model()->save). Then I get no response in my database? Why does your new function addUserId work for beforeSave() but not for when I am calling it from the controller?

Comment: To clarify, that means that the command    $model->user_id = $user->id; only sets the user id and can not update it?

Comment: `user_id` attribute sets before the **new** model is saved. You can update this attribute in existing model whenever you wish.

Comment: @Oldeje but is the update the same? $model->user_id = $user->id; I'm a bit confused as to why after I changed the function to this way of updating as opposed to the updateByPk - I was unable to simply call it from the controller and have it work.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you show me a piece of code from controller and from `beforeSave` method?

Comment: Function [beforeSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#beforeSave-detail) is automatically invoked before `CActiveRecord::save()` method if your model is valid.